# TypeError: post_tweet() missing 1 required positional argument: 'tweet'

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

```
import tweepy
from datetime import date

consumer_key = "consumer_key"
consumer_secret = "consumer_secret"
bearer_token = "bearer_token"
access_token = "access_token"
access_token_secret = "access_token_secret"

def create_tweet():
    current_date = date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    tweet_text = f"Wie fühlst du dich heute am {current_date}? Juckt mich nicht"
    return tweet_text

def post_tweet(self, tweet):
   # auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
   # auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
   # api = tweepy.API(auth)
   # api.update_status(tweet)
    client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token, consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
    auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    client.create_tweet(tweet)
    print("Tweet posted successfully!")

tweet = create_tweet()
post_tweet(tweet)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-df3d1416fa91> in <cell line: 27>()
     25 
     26 tweet = create_tweet()
---> 27 post_tweet(tweet)

TypeError: post_tweet() missing 1 required positional argument: 'tweet'
```

The script does not work due to the listed error. What do I need to change to make it run successfully?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  ```post_tweet``` isn't a method of a class.  It's just a function, so you can remove ```self``` in the parameters.

Comment: Remove the `self` parameter?

Comment: I had that before, then it gives me the following error:

`TypeError: Client.create_tweet() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Comment: Then you're not posting the full code. In any case the `self` makes no sense here

Comment: ok thanks! I should probably mention that this is within the Google Colab environment and it is all the code

Comment: just found the solution: 

`client.create_tweet(text=tweet)` 

instead of 

`client.create_tweet(tweet)`

Answer (score 0):

just found the solution: `client.create_tweet(text=tweet)` instead of `client.create_tweet(tweet)` and without the `self` as mentioned before.